# How do you create Foefire's Essence?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Reddit [has discovered quite a few new weapons](http://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/10evlk/conjured_weapon_models_info/) are available, all of them modelled after weapons that Guardians, Eles, and Mesmers can conjure. I'm specifically interested in [Foefire's Essence](http://www.guildhead.com/item/31077/foefires-essence-of-life).

The Mesmer weapons [have a predicable pattern](http://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/10evlk/conjured_weapon_models_info/c6cx0v7) of Mystic Coins + Eldritch Scroll + Ectoplasm + Tier 6 Weapon Components. I'm wondering if such a pattern exists for the Guardian weapons and, specifically, how you create Foefire's Essence.

[image: foefire image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Foefire's Essence can be created in the mystic forge by combining:

- 1 Eldritch Scroll
- 1 Gift of Light
- 70 Mystic Coins
- 250 Orichalcum Greatsword Blades

[Credit to Maisen from the official Guild Wars 2 Forums.](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/crafting/Foefire-s-Essence/page/4#post429301)

Comment: Oh come on Raven, like you needed any more reputation. :P

Answer (score -1):

It seems that there are a few ways to make it, yet ArenaNet has not confirmed a specific recipe for it.

There is a CHANCE to get it from:

-dragon chests

-placing 4 rare/exotic greatswords in the mystic forge

Source: https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/crafting/Foefire-s-Essence

Comment: Crafting designer says "I guess not EVERY recipe has been tested…" => there is a specific recipe for it, I'd assume :p

Comment: I HIGHLY doubt you can get it from random forges.